# Java Heap dump location , unix command line

Tags: java, unix, garbage-collection, heap-dump

I am facing a issue in which my heapdump is more than 2gb or maybe even 3gb is some cases , Now the problem is the heap dump gets created in a location (/home) which is of around 1gb only so after 1gb of heapdump the server gets deadlock(No other process can run) 
I just want to change the location of the Heapdump.

I am running my code on unix server , and increasing the size of /home dir is not an option.
I have tried using -XX:HeapDumpPath but it is not working. 
Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use -XX:HeapDumpPath='your location' according to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#DebuggingOptions

Comment: Yes already tried it , Not working i dont know why.
Is there any way i can set the location in my java code?

Comment: Please take into account double X and semicolumn in command line option.

Comment: Could you please run something like 'ps ax | grep java' on your server and show output for you java process here?

Comment: Yeah i can do that , first thing in the morning as i am out of office, and yeah XX dont worry :P

Comment: Could you please paste "java -version" output as well?

Comment: bash-4.2$ ps ax | grep java
  4980886      - A    576:00    /opt/informatica/dit/PowerCenter/9.1/java/bin/java
  3932622  pts/3 A     0:00 grep java
  3998134      - A    58:26 /opt/informatica/dit/PowerCenter/9.1/java/bin/java
bash-4.2$

Comment: bash-4.2$ java -version
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap6460sr12-20121025_01(SR12))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 AIX ppc64-64 jvmap6460sr12-20121024_126067 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20121024_126067
JIT  - r9_20120914_26057
GC   - 20120928_AA)
JCL  - 20121014_01
bash-4.2$

Comment: It seems you use IBM JVM. I've never used it but found this parameter here (https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21242497#Default_Settings_For_Dumps).
Please try to play with it:
        -Xdump:java:defaults:file=dumps/%pid/javacore-%seq.txt

Try to change dumps/%pid/javacore-%seq.txt to your own path.

Answer (score 0):

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xdump:heap:label=/dumps/heapdump.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S.%pid.%seq.phd" 
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xdump:java:label=/dumps/javacore.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S.%pid.%seq.txt" 
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xdump:system:label=/dumps/core.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S.%pid.%seq.dmp" 
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xdump:snap:label=/dumps/Snap.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S.%pid.%seq.trc" 
(Optional) JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xdump:what"
```

You can change the JAVA_OPTS env variable or simple add individual -Xdump cmds from where you are running the code.
like 
`java -d64 -Xdump:heap:label=/${INFA_ROOT}/temp/heapdump.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S.%pid.%seq.phd -Xmx4g ...rest of the arrgs.`

Comment: From your answer I assume you are using the IBM JVM. (-Xdump is an IBM specific option.) If it is a recent version you can use -Xdump:directory=/dumps to relocate all the dump files with non-absolute paths set with one option instead of resetting all the different types of dumps.
See: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.70.doc/diag/tools/dumpagents_syntax.html

Comment: Okay.. thanks for the update Hellyer.
I try it myself.